# how to Delete parent Node of XML by checking the Value of it in PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have an XML Like  below

```
<Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s245"><Data ss:Type="String">ABSOLUTE</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Yellow</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Exist</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s258"/>
</Row>
<Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s229"><Data ss:Type="String">PART3</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Part3 Description</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Buy_Part</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s258"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="13.5"><Cell ss:StyleID="s245"><Data ss:Type="String">PART3</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Part3 Description</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Buy_Part</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s258"/>
</Row>
```

I want to delete the Nodes of the XML searching for the Value inside the Node.

Example I want to search for the Value "PART3" in the above example and want to delete  COmplete Node containing that Value. So the Output should be only as below

```
<Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s245"><Data ss:Type="String">ABSOLUTE</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Yellow</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Exist</Data></Cell>
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s258"/>
</Row>
```

I have written below script

```
$doc = new DOMDOcument;
    $doc->loadxml($xmldata);
    $item_id = "PART3";
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    foreach($xpath->query('//Row[Cell/Data="' . $item_id . '"]') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
 echo $doc->savexml();
```

But it displays the complete XML without deleting.
Please Help Me how to delete The node by searching for the Value PART3 since the XML will be Very BIG and it contains lots of `<ROW><CELL><DATA></Data></Cell><ROW>`

Comment: The code you give works for me. When I run it, I get the XML without the `<Row>` nodes having a `<Data>` child with text value *PART3* - in other words, the XML only contains the `<Row>` Node containing *ABSOLUTE*

Comment: Can You please paste the complete code you have ran.. I am running this in UNIX

Comment: I have run your code and your XML (assigned it to a variable with HEREDOC for that matter). It gives a lot of Warnings about the Namespace prefix ss not being defined, but apart from that, it does what you were asking for.

Comment: Hi Gorden ,

The XML i have is very BIG and that XML is created on runtime. SO i just wanted to test the above snippet . For that I have assigned it like below
     $xmldata =  " <Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s245"><Data ss:Type="String">ABSOLUTE</Data></Cell> 
   <Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Yellow</Data></Cell> 
   <Cell ...<remaining >..
; 
      

I was getting an error CAn u please say how u assigned it?

Comment: I used PHP's [HEREDOC syntax](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks for the HereDOC syntax it was a new information for me... But about the out put i get as <?xml version="1.0"?> 

But what i need is 
    <Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s245"><Data ss:Type="String">ABSOLUTE</Data></Cell> 
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Yellow</Data></Cell> 
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="String">Exist</Data></Cell> 
<Cell ><Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data></Cell> 
<Cell ss:StyleID="s258"/> 
</Row>

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what the issue is then.

Comment: Hi GORDON,

Ya now got the rite output with the snippets, when added one more parent node. But now while running the actual XML i has many other nodes like <Style><Alignment />
<Borders><Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
<Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
<Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
<Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
</Borders>
</Style>..
So  after this comes my <ROW><CELL><DATA> will it be the problem?

Comment: Should not be a problem because you are using `//` in your XPath which means all nodes anywhere in the document

Comment: Hi Jorden IF possible could You get me ur mail ID so that I can sent the Full XML..Please

Comment: Hi did some debugging and found out because having the below snippet  at the begining of the XML i am not able to get expected result.

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

Please let me know how to tackle this?

Comment: Hi Sorry to post again and again.. just debugged again and at last got the exact reason y that was not working properly because of the  line

xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" in the workbook node. Please let me know how to tackle this one line

Comment: If this is Excel, why not use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ to manipulate it?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH looks correct...just curious, but you mention that this is a sample snippet of XML. Is maybe the casing on the XML tags in the actual XML slightly different, causing a mis-match in your XPATH?

Comment: Hi RObert.. 

But while I test with this snippets also I am not getting the Output here It gets deleted completly